# api_platform produces Error "no handler found for uri [/index/_doc/_search] and method [POST]"

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, api-platform.com

When trying to implement elasticsearch (v7.9.3) via the fos_elastica-bundle (v6.0.0) into my Symfony (v5.3.10) - App with api_platform (v2.6.6), I keep on getting this error:

```
"{"error":"no handler found for uri [//posts/_doc/_search] and method [POST]"}",
```

My api_platform.yaml reads:

```
api_platform:
    [...]
    elasticsearch:
        hosts: [ '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' ]
        mapping:
            App\Document\Post:
                index: posts
```

and my fos_elastica.yaml:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        posts:
            properties:
                id:
                    "type": "keyword"
                source: ~
                title: ~
                description: ~
                body: ~
                children: ~
                tags: ~
                originalContent: ~
            persistence:
                driver: mongodb
                model: App\Document\Post
```

By debugging the fos-elastica Bundle, I found out that the Elastica-Connector correctly triggers a [POST]-Request to "/posts/_doc/_search" with this request body:

```
{"sort":[{"id":{"order":"asc"}}],"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":30,"from":0}
```

If I use the Kibana Dev Tools Console and trigger an identical request

```
POST /posts/_doc/_search
  {"sort":[{"id":{"order":"asc"}}],"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":30,"from":60}
```

I do get results from elasticsearch as expected:

```
#! Deprecation: [types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated.
    {
      "took" : 12,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 3082,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "posts",
            "_type" : "_doc",
[...]
```

Apart from the deprecation notice, everything seems fine.

Does anyone have an idea why the api_platform integration of the fos_elastica-bundle does not work as expected and keeps on returning the "no handler found"-error message?

Comment: is there an extra leading `/` in your PHP path? The two `/`s to start here: `//posts/_doc/_search'` makes me nervous

Comment: Yes, there is a leading / in the path which is computed by api_platform. I don´t know where it comes from, but I doubt that it causes the described error.

If I use the Kibana Dev Tools Console to trigger a request with two leading slashes (i.e. POST //posts/_doc/_search), I still get the same (correct) response.

Comment: Still haven´t found a solution. Anyone out there to assist?

Answer (score 0):

I have now helped myself by creating a custom ApiResource - filter

```
#[ApiFilter(FulltextFilter::class, arguments: ['index' => 'post'], properties: ['body','description','tag'])]
```

My custom filter implements `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\MongoDbOdm\Filter\FilterInterface`, directly communicates with the ElasticSearch server, sends a query to search the specified index (posts) and adds another match()-directive to the aggregationBuilder with a set of IDs matching the original search:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\MongoDbOdm\Filter\FilterInterface;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Aggregation\Builder;
use Elastica\Result;
use Elastica\Client;
use Elastica\Query;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Type;

/**
 * Filter the collection by given properties.
 *
 */
final class FulltextFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    protected $index = '';
    protected $properties = [];
    protected $client;
    protected $searchParameterName;
    protected $maxResultsParameterName;
    const DEFAULT_MAX_RESULTS = 200;
    public function __construct(Client $client, string $index = '', string $maxResultsParameterName = 'amount', string $searchParameterName = 'query', array $properties = []) {
        $this->index = $index;
        $this->properties = $properties;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->searchParameterName = $searchParameterName;
        $this->maxResultsParameterName = $maxResultsParameterName;
    }
    public function getFilteredIds($searchterm, $index = null, $properties = null, $maxResults = null) {
        $matches = [];
        if (is_null($properties)) {
            $properties = array_keys($this->properties);
        }
        foreach ($properties as $propertyName) {
            array_push($matches, ['match'=>[$propertyName => $searchterm]]);
        }
        $queryObject = ['query' => ['bool' => ['should' => $matches]]];
        $queryObject['size'] = (int) $maxResults >0 ? (int) $maxResults : self::DEFAULT_MAX_RESULTS;

        $query = new Query();
        $response = $this->client->getIndex($index ?? $this->index)
            ->search($query->setRawQuery($queryObject))
            ->getResults();
        return array_map(function(Result $result) {return $result->getHit()['_source']['id'];}, $response);

    }

    public function apply(Builder $aggregationBuilder, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array &$context = [])
    {
        $maxResults = $context['filters'][$this->maxResultsParameterName] ?? null;
        $searchterm = $context['filters'][$this->searchParameterName] ?? false;
        if ($searchterm !== false) {
            $aggregationBuilder->match()->field('id')->in($this->getFilteredIds($searchterm, null, null, $maxResults));
        }
    }

    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

This solution might not be as elegant as using the ElasticSearch-Connector natively provided by api_platform, but it is fairly performant and it works.

However, if someone comes up with a solution to fix the depicted ES-Connector issue with api_platform, please feel free to share it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, FOS Elastica requires an ES URL with an ending slash. But Api Platform requires a URL without ending slash.

We usually define the URL in .env file and then recall it in config files.
To solve the problem, we could define the URL in .env without endling slash and add the slash to the FOS Elastica config.

```
# .env

###> friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ###
ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200
###< friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ###
```

```yaml
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml

api_platform:
    elasticsearch:
        enabled: true
        hosts: [ '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' ]
```

```yaml
# config/packages/fos_elastica.yaml

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%/' }
```