# no handler found for uri [<index>/_doc/<document_id>/_update] and method [POST]

Tags: go, elasticsearch

Currently, i am using client go-elasticsearch version `v7.8.0` and elastic of version `8.1.2`. the elastic search got updated from version `7.x`

Now when I try to update the document it fails with the following error.

There are some stackoverflow answer i came through like this one but didn't help

[api_platform produces Error "no handler found for uri [/index/_doc/_search] and method [POST]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334754/api-platform-produces-error-no-handler-found-for-uri-index-doc-search-and)

```
elasticsearch response on failure while updating- {"error":"no handler found for uri [/<index>/_doc/<doc_id>/_update?retry_on_conflict=2] and method [POST]"
```

Sample query for update:

```
{"doc":{"info":{"description":"test description","slug":"test"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a Go client for 7.8.0 with and Elasticsearch server 8.1.2, they are not compatible. You need to upgrade your Go client to the [same 8.1 version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/go-api/current/index.html)

Comment: yes, the upgrade worked as I see their update implementation is quite different now. Thanks a lot, Val:))

Answer (score 2):

Please try use the endpoint `/{index}/_update/{id}` instead. The one you used is deprecated and removed in 8.1.

Reference:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update-api-request

Comment: Thanks very much! I have the same problem. And it is solved by your answer.